# Changing body to yield all values of iterable

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield, iterable

I'm supposed to write a generator that takes any number of iterables and produces the 1st element from the 1st argument, 1st element from 2nd argument, ..., 2nd element from 1st element, 2nd element from 2nd argument, etc.

```
def alternate(*args):
    iterable = [iter(a) for a in args]
    try:
        while True:
            for a in iterable:
                yield next(a)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Currently, my output is 'afhbgic' instead of 'afhbgicjdke'.

How I can change my code so that it prints the right output?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is where you're catching `StopIteration`. Since it's outside your `while` loop when the first iterator is empty you exit the while loop and don't examine any more iterators. Changing it to this should *almost* do the trick (untested):

```
def alternate(*args):
    iterator = [iter(arg) for arg in args]

    while True:
        for it in iterator:
            try:
                yield next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
```

Except now it'd hang forever after giving the correct answer because `next(it)` with throw `StopIteration` for each iterator once they're all empty but you'll catch that and keep going around your loop. There's a number of ways around that though. For example:

```
def alternate(*args):
    iterators = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    next_iterators = []

    while len(iterators) > 0:
        for it in iterators:
            try:
                yield next(it)
                # only get here if next(it) returned a valid element
                next_iterators.append(it)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        iterators = next_iterators
        next_iterators = []
```

Comment: Your modified version still hangs - you'd need to change the loop condition to `while iterators` or something like that to make it not hang.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def alternate(*args):
    iterator = [iter(arg) for arg in args]

    L = len(iterator)
    while L > 0:
        which = 0
        while which < L:
            try:
                yield next(iterator[which])
                which += 1
            except StopIteration:
                del iterator[which]
                L -= 1
```

**Output:**

```
'afhbgicjdke'
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a while loop and for loop instead of 2 while loops?

Comment: It might be possible, but I would not recommend it here, unless a good reason is given. A `for` loop implementation of this would add a bit of avoidable clutter, imho. That's because your `for` loop would be deleting from the same iterable called `iterator` which it would be iterating over